# iCal event invite colors

Tags: ical, defaults

I receive ical event invites from my boss all time. Once I accept the invite and it goes to the ical on my mac, the color of the event changes into the default blue on my mac. My question is, how do I keep the original color of the invite reflect on my calendar? For example, if the color of the event on my boss' mac was orange, how do I keep it's orange color once I accept the invite and it appears on my calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible. When you accept an invitation you can choose one of your calendars (which can have different colors) to add the appointment. If you don't choose a calendar it will go to your default calendar.

So the only work around I can think of, is to create the same calendars that your boss has, and then select the appropriate one when you receive an invitation.

Comment: Yep. After some scouring around the interwebs, I do believe it boils down to just mimicking the colors of my boss' calendars. Thanks, guys. =D